# Python reading the entire file as one line

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-read

I have a data file like the following.

```
Index   Code    Pos1    Strand  Chr2    Pos2    length  blocks
1   G32_bkd.ctx:Vu01(old4)  62739   47+9-   Vu01(old4)  63651   790 0
2   G32_bkd.ctx:Vu01(old4)  441403  10+0-   Vu01(old4)  446263  4893    0
3   G32_bkd.ctx:Vu01(old4)  450546  15+0-   Vu01(old4)  451091  576 0
4   G32_bkd.ctx:Vu01(old4)  459741  10+0-   Vu01(old4)  460841  1068    0
5   G32_bkd.ctx:Vu01(old4)  612262  14+0-   Vu01(old4)  629013  16788   0
6   G32_bkd.ctx:Vu01(old4)  688380  23+0-   Vu01(old4)  693207  4872    0
7   G32_bkd.ctx:Vu01(old4)  730643  12+0-   Vu01(old4)  740497  7011    0
8   G32_bkd.ctx:Vu01(old4)  834116  16+1-   Vu01(old4)  835797  1752    0
```

I want to read the header line seperately and then read each line in a for loop. My code is

```
with open(file) as f:
    title_line = f.readline()
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        cols = line.split()
```

When I checked `print(line)` inside the `for` loop, it doesn't print anything. But when I checked `print(title_line)`, the entire file is printed preserving the exact format in the file. What went wrong?

N.B. So, I just copied and pasted the whole file and saved it in a different name and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that could cause that behavior would be if Python is for some reason not liking the end of line chars from the original file.

To confirm that, on Linux you could use `od -t a file | less`, and inspect what's in there.   Perhaps the file conforms to a different Operating System standard?  If not on Linux, you can use Python itself to print each char with `ord` to see what it is using (\n, \r, \r\n).

If that's the case, you have some options:

- For Python 2, you could open the file in *Universal newlines* mode.  That is, "U":

  - `open (file, "U")`
  - That's a quick and easy way to confirm this is indeed the issue and fix it, but not recommended for long term
- Otherwise, you can use `io.open` instead of `open`, and use its `newline=` argument.  The default, `None`, should be what you need.

If this does not fix your issue, please provide:

- The Operating System you're using
- The Python version you're using
- The source Operating System of the original file

As an unrelated side note, I'd suggest you check Python's built-in `csv` module for reading your file.  It seems like a perfect fit (the `csv` module can be configured to use spaces or tabs, instead of commas)

**References**

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open
- https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your have a file 'yourfile.txt' and its size is not big.

```
f = open('yourfile.txt','r')
```

Skipping the title_line in readlines.

```
for line in f.readlines()[1:]:
    line = line.strip()
    cols = line.split()
    # output the result
    print ",".join(x for x in cols)
```